# Profile a link to my LinkedIn profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

As my LinkedIn profile contains recommendations, etc., I wish my CV to link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers) surports markup, this is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

File a link somewhere in the "Projects and Links" section perhaps?